# Magento 1.1 EE - Fatal error: Class 'Mage_MyPlugin_Helper_Data'

Tags: php, magento, module

Basically, im making a Plugin for Magento , And when i install it i always get a Fatal Error from Mage.php saying my class is not found - Heres My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Johnhudson_MyPlugin>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Johnhudson_MyPlugin>
  </modules>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <adminhtml>
        <args>
          <modules>
            <Johnhudson_MyPlugin after="Mage_Adminhtml">Johnhudson_MyPlugin</Johnhudson_MyPlugin>
          </modules>
        </args>
      </adminhtml>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <johnhudson_myplugin>
        <class>Johnhudson_MyPlugin_Helper</class>
      </johnhudson_myplugin>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

And my Helper class:

```
<?php
class Johnhudson_MyPlugin_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

And when I try installing it and clearing the Cache, it always gives me a Fatal Error , and somehow changes my "Johnhudson" package name to "Mage" which displays as "Mage_MyPlugin_Helper_Data", my Helper file is Saved as Data.php as required.

Answer (score 0):

Try without vender in helper class declare, change this **johnhudson_myplugin** to **myplugin** in global -> helpers section

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the package_module to module

```
    <global>
    <helpers>
      <johnhudson_myplugin>
        <class>Johnhudson_MyPlugin_Helper</class>
      </johnhudson_myplugin>
    </helpers>
  </global>
```